# What podcast/streaming tools are available?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, streaming, podcast

I want to be able to do one or all of the followings:

- Talk to my computer and be heard over a network (Crazy O.o)
- Live Video Streaming (Watch a Video and share over network)
- Live Audio streaming (Listen to song and share over network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet DJ Console is great for

- talking to your computer and be heard over a network
- live audio streaming

http://idjc.sourceforge.net/tour_main.html

VLC media player is great for

- Live Video streaming

http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/